# Is there a way to customize the 403 message using Google Auth?

Tags: google-chrome, google-oauth, google-compute-engine

When I log in with an account which does not belong to the expected domain, this message is shown (which is correct).
I think this message is kind of ugly and not understandable for a non-developer person. Is there a way to modify this message in the Google Cloud Console or inside the OAuth code? I would like to display for example:

The email you used does not belong to the **happy.com** domain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fount this [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/158013110) In the Public Issue Tracker, and there they suggest to follow the steps of [Customize the rejected-app message](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en#blockedmessage). Basically it mentions:

1. Your current account, user@domain.com, doesn't have permission to do these steps. To continue, switch to an administrator account. This will open the Google Admin console.
   Switch to administrator account now or Learn more
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to "" and then Security and then API controls.
3. Under App access control, go to the Settings section.
4. Type your custom text in the box under the following message: Show this message if a user tries to use an app that can’t access restricted Google services.
5. Click SAVE.

If this doesn't make it,  I would recommend you to comment on that [FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/158013110)  in which they mentioned:

> I have filed this feature request internally.

You might also want to [‘star’](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) the [FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/158013110) to ensure that you receive updates about it. You can also [adjust notification](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/set-notification-preferences) settings by clicking the gear icon in the top right corner and selecting settings.